# Rename field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, rest

I have two JSON objects, In each, there is a firstname field. I want to rename firstname to name, also want to import the existing firstname values to name, using mongoose.

**Schema:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const user = new Schema({
  firstname:{ type:String },
  lastname:{ type:String },
  username:{ type:String },
  password:{ type:String },
  user_type:{ type:String },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', user)
```

**Data Sample:**

```
_id: "5bf5fbef16a06667027eecc2", firstname: "Hareesh", lastname: "Pitchikala", username: "123", password: "123", user_type: "employer", __v: 0
```

Comment: This question is about Mongoose but it was flagged duplicate and link to MongoDB.

Come on, it's not the same

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, you'll need to add `name` to your schema so it becomes:

```js
const user = new Schema({
    name: { type:String },
    firstname: { type:String }, //keep this for now
    lastname: { type:String },
    username: { type:String },
    password: { type:String },
    user_type: { type:String },
});
```

Now, in your app code somewhere, you'll need to run this:

```js
User.updateMany({}, { $rename: { firstname: 'name' } }, { multi: true }, function(err, blocks) {
    if(err) { throw err; }
    console.log('done!');
});
```

Now, you can remove `firstname` from your schema if you wish.

Comment: Not sure but I have to add `strict:false` to the snippet to get it working:

Also it said `DeprecationWarning: collection.update is deprecated. Use updateOne, updateMany, or bulkWrite instead.`

So I used `upadateMany`
Fullcode: 
```
User.updateMany(
      {},
      { $rename: { firstname: 'name' } },
      { multi: true, strict: false },
      function (error) {
        if (error) {
          throw error;
        }
        console.log('done!');
      }
    );
```

Comment: `{ multi: true }`will be ignored. From docs: "...MongoDB will update all documents that match filter [...] regardless of the value of the multi option."

Answer (score 0):

Documents can be updated as below:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},{ $rename: { "firstname": "name" } } );
```

Comment: this isn't `using mongoose` - which is what the OP requested.

Comment: It is using mongoose though...

Comment: @TorbenNordtorp `db.collection` isn't mongoose syntax, it's the MongoDB driver.