# mongoDB : renaming column name in all collection IS NOT UPDATING

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

example I got

```
db.collection.update({}, {$rename: {'XUknown': 'XString'}}, false, true);
```

I tried in nodejs.

```
await PRODUCT.update(
    {},
    { $rename: { "product_code": "group_code" } }, false, true
  )
    .then((data) => {
      return res.status(200).json(data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(400).json({ error: error, message: 'not possible' })
    })
```

response I got ..it not updating

```
{
    "acknowledged": false
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `false, true`?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question. you can find answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53447772/7937057

Comment: but.. its not updating.. its giving response as "acknowledged": false

Comment: false, true for upsert, multi

Comment: In this case, you should use: {  upsert: false,  multi: true}, like so: db.collection.update({}, {$rename: {'XUknown': 'XString'}}, {  upsert: false,  multi: true});

Comment: is it applicable to mongodb version 5?

Comment: Yes. see playground here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/vzuXd6VzPKx

Comment: Thanks all for the reply.. its issue with db role.. I have assigned the update role to the user.. then it works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue... ensure you didn't remove the old field from your schema as at the point of running that command. once you run the command and you check your db and notice the changes has been effected, then you can remove the old field from your schema. else it won't work. That is how i solved mine